# Finite automata

Tags: finite-automata

I want to ask about this statement.

"there exist finite automata that have a cycle, but still only accept a finite language"

is it true this statement? please give me a reason?

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to tell what your understanding of the problem is.  When a finite automaton is presented with an input, what are the possible outcomes?  Which of these constitute "accepting" the input?  What restriction does "only accept a finite language" impose on the outcomes?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The empty language is finite.